# Ler um XML em outro domínio

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

é possível ler um xml em outro domínio?
ex:

```
http://mfmradio.fr/winradio/prog10.xml?player201507291645
```

fiz o código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var i;
        var timer,timeout2;
        $(document).ready(function(){
            LoadProg = function(timeout){
                timeout2 = timeout;
                $.ajax({
                    cache: "false",
                    type: "POST",
                                        url: 'http://mfmradio.fr/winradio/prog10.xml?player201507291645',
                                        dataType: 'xml',
                    success: function(xml, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
                        $('#title-list').html('');

                        var pochetteEnCours = $(xml).find('morceau:eq(0)').find('pochette').text();
                        var pochetteEnCours = pochetteEnCours.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");



                        $('<li class="pochette"><\/li>').html(
                            pochette
                        ).appendTo('#title-list');
                        $('<li class="artiste"><\/li>').html(
                            $(xml).find('morceau:eq(0)').find('chanteur').text()
                        ).appendTo('#title-list');
                        $('<li class="titre"><\/li>').html(
                            $(xml).find('morceau:eq(0)').find('chanson').text()
                        ).appendTo('#title-list');

                        var musiqueEnCours = "J'écoute " + $(xml).find('morceau:eq(0)').find('chanteur').text() + " - " + $(xml).find('morceau:eq(0)').find('chanson').text();
                        $('<iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.html?via=MFMRadio&amp;text='+musiqueEnCours+'&amp;count=horizontal" style = "width: 110px; hauteur: 20px; position:absolute; margin-top:80px; margin-left:190px;"></iframe>').appendTo('#button_twitter');

                        // Last Titles

                        $('#last-titles-list').html('');
                        $('prog morceau:gt(0):lt(4)', xml).each(function(){

                            var pochetteArchive = $(this).find('pochette').text();
                            var pochetteArchive = pochetteArchive.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");

                            if( (typeof( pochetteArchive ) != "undefined") && (pochetteArchive != '') ){
                                var pochette = '<img src="' + $(this).find('pochette').text() +'"/>';
                            }else{
                                var pochette = '<img src="/media/pochette.png"/>';
                            }

                            $('<li><\/li>').append(
                                $('<span class="pochette"><\/span>').html(pochette)
                            ).append(
                                $('<span class="artiste"><\/span>').html($(this).find('chanteur').text())
                            ).append(
                                $('<span class="titre"><\/span>').html($(this).find('chanson').text())
                            ).appendTo('#last-titles-list');
                        });

                    }
                });

                timer = setTimeout("LoadProg(timeout2)", timeout);
            }
        });


        $(document).ready(function(){
            LoadProg(20000);
        });


    </script>
```

Porém retorna o erro:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mfmradio.fr/winradio/prog10.xml?player201507291645. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.doratiotto.com.br' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Como não tenho acesso ao dominio não poderia por exemplo criar um crossdomain.xml

Comment: já tentou o $.getJson do jquery?

Comment: Não vai dar. A não ser que você use uma linguagem como PHP para ler um arquivo externo. A política da mesma origem vai de bloquear, e você não vai conseguir ler esse arquivo que está em domínio externo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o servidor `http://mfmradio.fr` usando apache e o xml for *estático*, você pode usar .htaccess com mod_headers, por exemplo:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Isto irá permitir qualquer dominio externo acessar o `.xml`, para definir um domínio especifico troque o `*` por uma url.

---

Se você não tiver acesso aos arquivos do `http://mfmradio.fr`, então será necessário criar um **"proxy"** pra ler este xml, se o servidor que está o ajax estiver usando php, você pode usar `curl`, por exemplo:

Crie um arquivo chamado **proxy.php**:

```
<?php
if (false === isset($_GET['url'])) {
   echo 'Url não definida';
   exit;
}

$url = $_GET['url'];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 80);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
$contentType = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);

header('Content-Type: ' . $contentType);

echo $data;
```

E no **Ajax** deve ficar algo como:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: "false",
    type: "POST",
    url: 'proxy.php?url=' + encodeUri('http://mfmradio.fr/winradio/prog10.xml?player201507291645'),
    dataType: 'xml',
```

Comment: Eu tentei criar algo nesse sentido antes de postar minha resposta, mas não consegui resultado, não sei se por estar testando de `localhost`.

Comment: Acredito que tenha sido a falta do user-agent @KaduAmaral ou outro header. Testei o meu proxy com a url `http://mfmradio.fr/winradio/prog10.xml?player201507291645` e trouxe o xml perfeitamente. No seu caso pode ter sido a falta do Content-Type ou do useragent mesmo.

Comment: Descobri o problema, é o proxy da empresa. :)

Comment: Então se você acessar `http://mfmradio.fr/winradio/prog10.xml?player201507291645` diretamente também não funciona? Só curiosidade mesmo kk

Comment: Funciona... Depois eu vou testar aqui em casa, sem proxy pra tirar o veredito.

Answer (score 1):

É possível, desde que o proprietário do domínio permita a requisição:

**PHP:**

```
// Permite apenas alguns domínios
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://mysite1.com');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.mysite2.com');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.mysite2.com');

// Permite QUALQUER domínio
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  // Permite qualquer domínio
```

**HTACCESS**

```
# Permite alguns domínios
SetEnvIf Origin "^http(s)?://(.+\.)?(domain\.org|domain2\.com)$" origin_is=$0 
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{origin_is}e env=origin_is

# Permite QUALQUER domínio
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Acredito que o *Access Control* vem bloqueado por padrão, mante-lo habilitado em toda e qualquer ocasião seria um falha na segurança.

Exemplo da falha:

> Imagine site chamado `faceboock.com` e ele fosse apenas uma página em branco que requisitasse por AJAX a página de *login* do Facebook e alterasse apenas o `action` do formulário de login para `http://faceboock.com/rouba-conta-facebook.php`.